# Barplot orientation -

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am new to creating graphs with Latex. The graph on the right is the original graph, I then decided it would look better if I change color for each classifier type and add the value of the bar on top. I'm struggling to have the labels on the bottom.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, landspace, leqno]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
      \footnotesize{
     \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
            \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                title=Precision Rate,
                symbolic x coords={NB1,  NB2, SVM1, SVM2, DT1, DT2, LR1, LR2},
                xtick=data,
               nodes near coords,
                every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
                nodes near coords align={vertical},
                nodes/.style={font=\footnotesize},
              ]
                \addplot[fill=blue!30] plot coordinates { 
                    (NB1,   0.36)
                    (NB2,   0.96)
                    };
                \addplot[fill=teal!30] plot coordinates { 
                    (SVM1,  0.93)
                    (SVM2,  0.98)
                    };
              \addplot[fill=cyan!30] plot coordinates { 
                    (DT1,   0.93)
                    (DT2,   0.94)
                    };
               \addplot[fill=orange!30] plot coordinates { 
                     (LR1,   0.94)
                    (LR2,   0.99) 
                };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{document}
```

[image: current bar-plot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Besides making your example TeXable you need to define a value for *each* bar so that `xtick` doensn't get confused. And because you want to ignore the "zeros" I used `ybar stacked`. Last I moved the lables to the top of the bars which would otherwise be centered in the bars. I think that is your desired output, right?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        thick,
        scale=0.8,
        font=\footnotesize,
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked,
            width=9cm,
            title=Precision Rate,
            symbolic x coords={NB1, NB2, SVM1, SVM2, DT1, DT2, LR1, LR2},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            % move `nodes near coords' to the top of the bars
            every node near coord/.style={
                at={(axis cs:{[normalized]\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})},
                anchor=south,
            },
        ]
            \addplot[fill=blue!30] plot coordinates {
                (NB1, 0.36) (NB2, 0.96) (SVM1,0)    (SVM2,0)
                (DT1, 0)    (DT2, 0)    (LR1, 0)    (LR2, 0)
            };
            \addplot[fill=teal!30] plot coordinates {
                (NB1, 0)    (NB2, 0)    (SVM1,0.93) (SVM2,0.98)
                (DT1, 0)    (DT2, 0)    (LR1, 0)    (LR2, 0)
            };
            \addplot[fill=cyan!30] plot coordinates {
                (NB1, 0)    (NB2, 0)    (SVM1,0)    (SVM2,0)
                (DT1, 0.93) (DT2, 0.94) (LR1, 0)    (LR2, 0)
            };
            \addplot[fill=orange!30] plot coordinates {
                (NB1, 0)    (NB2, 0)    (SVM1,0)    (SVM2,0)
                (DT1, 0)    (DT2, 0)    (LR1, 0.94) (LR2, 0.99)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for you help! When I use you code I get an error: ! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.13' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/
When I remove '\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}', I get an error - Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'NB1' as a floating point number.

Comment: @OAK, my solution only works for PGFPlots v1.13 and with the error message presented I think that you have an older version installed, right? (If you don't know your version write `\listfiles` above the `\documentclass`, TeX any minimal example which does not cause an error and have a look at the LOG file.) So my advice is: update to v1.13.

Comment: I tried the code in an empty document and it works. It seems I have packages that conflict with pgfplot. I have version 1.13.

Comment: @OAK, can you TeX the code above without any error message? Because then it is unlikely that another package conflicts with PGFPlots. When it is one, then PGF/tikz. Which version do you have there?

Comment: tikz.sty  v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
pgf.sty v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14). The TeX code you provided in works on a separate TeX file. Is that what you mean 'can you TeX the code above without any error message?'?

Comment: @OAK, yes, that is what I meant. Maybe you should first update your tikz to v3.0.1a and then have a look, if the error still apears in your other document. If the error still persists, make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to find out what constallation causes the error. If you think this is a bug in one of the packages, you can e.g. create a [ticket in the bug tracker of PGFPlots](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs) or state it here, if you don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I think the package is up to date. What is really strange is the fact that on a separate document everything works fine. Seems to me it has to be a conflict with a package.

Comment: @OAK, because it starts to get a bit off-topic, I think it's best to discuss this on chat. Care to join me to [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35326/discussion-between-oak-and-stefan-pinnow)?

Comment: @OAK, if you think my answer was useful, think of accepting it. To decide whether you should (already) mark my answer as accepted, maybe [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/95441) helps.